# iframe google translate code?

Tags: asp.net

I am using following code to add a google translator to my page header. But if I move it inside page content its not displaying anything. How to get the same translator box in iframe.

```
<div id="google_translate_element" class="langSwitch"></div>
<script>
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({
    pageLanguage: 'en',
    includedLanguages: 'af,sq,ar,hy,az,eu,be,bg,ca,zh-CN,zh-TW,hr,cs,da,nl,en,et,tl,fi,fr,gl,ka,de,el,ht,iw,hi,hu,is,id,ga,it,ja,ko,la,lv,lt,mk,ms,mt,no,fa,pl,pt,ro,ru,sr,sk,sl,es,sw,sv,th,tr,uk,ur,vi,cy,yi',
    gaTrack: true,
    gaId: 'UA-2585500-1',
    layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE
  }, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check your `<script src`, it's `//translate.google.com` instead of `http://translate.google.com/`.

Comment: It still working if I keep on my header, but my page contnet part will not accept any javascripts. So its not recognizing my javscript in content area. How to display it in the page?